# Importing anything from '@storybook/angular' cause error "Interface 'NodeRequire' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Require' and 'WebpackRequire'"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, storybook

I configured storybook in Angular app and tried running following first story using storybook demo components.

```
import { Button } from '@storybook/angular/demo';

export default { title: 'My Button' };

export const withText = () => ({
  component: Button,
  props: {
    text: 'Hello Button',
  },
});

export const withEmoji = () => ({
  component: Button,
  props: {
    text: '   ',
  },
});
```

This above example works perfectly fine. Now when I import anything from `@storybook/angular` like this

```
import { moduleMetadata } from '@storybook/angular';
// OR
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/angular';
```

Build breaks with following errors

```
ERROR in node_modules/@types/webpack-env/index.d.ts(281,11):
TS2320: Interface 'NodeRequire' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Require' and 'WebpackRequire'.
  Named property 'context' of types 'Require' and 'WebpackRequire' are not identical.

ERROR in node_modules/@types/webpack-env/index.d.ts(281,11):
TS2320: Interface 'NodeRequire' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Require' and 'WebpackRequire'.
  Named property 'ensure' of types 'Require' and 'WebpackRequire' are not identical.

ERROR in node_modules/@types/webpack-env/index.d.ts(354,11):
TS2320: Interface 'NodeModule' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Module' and 'WebpackModule'.
  Named property 'hot' of types 'Module' and 'WebpackModule' are not identical.
```

I tried multiple solutions but none of them worked.

**Update:**
I was able temporarily fix it to move forward by modifying the interfaces in `node_modules/@types/webpack-env/index.d.ts`

```
// this line
interface NodeModule extends NodeJS.Module {}
// replaced with
interface NodeModule {}
```

Similarly

```
interface NodeRequire extends NodeJS.Require {}
// replaced with
interface NodeRequire {}
```

and finally

```
interface Module extends __WebpackModuleApi.Module {}
// replaced with
interface Module {}
```